# Standard Datepicker Year values

Tags: visualforce, calendar

I have used date field in my visualforce page.By default the datpicker is showing values upto year 2012.but i nedd to insert few more years before 2012.How can i implement this as it is the default calendar provided by salesforce.

Comment: This code is not working in Internet explorer 8. Please let me know what changes need to be done to make it work in IE8. Thanks a lot. --JP

Comment: Hey @Jayaprakash, I appreciate you need more rep points to comment. This relates to an [IE bug going back seven years](http://muffinresearch.co.uk/archives/2006/07/19/bug-when-creating-select-options-using-innerhtml-in-ie/). I've updated my answer with an IE8-compatible approach.

Answer (score 16):

It's a lot of tweaking to get this injected into standard pages... worst case, just type the year in :P reinventing vs decorating the native picker is an interesting debate, all of us with unique circumstances!

1. Setup > Customize > User Interface
2. Check [X] Show Custom Sidebar Components on All Pages
3. Create a new Home Page Component (HTML, narrow) called "Date Picker Years" containing:

   ```
   <script>
     (function() {
       var windowOnload = window.onload;
       window.onload = function() {
         if (windowOnload) windowOnload();
         var select = document.getElementById('calYearPicker');
         if (!select) return;

         select.innerHTML = '';
         var startYear = new Date().getFullYear() - 90;
         for (var year = startYear; year < startYear + 100; year++) {
           select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(year, year);
         }
       }
     }());
   </script>
   ```
4. Place that Component on your Home Page Layout.

   [image: extra years in datepicker]

Edit - was asked for some explanation:

- the wrapper `(function() { ... }());` prevents vars polluting the global scope
- don't just trample the `window.onload` function, store it and call it ([interceptor pattern](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/DecoratedCommand.html))
- `calYearPicker` could disappear any time; if so, ["get out of dodge quick"](http://andrewfawcett.wordpress.com/) by returning early

Comment: Nice work Derp!

Comment: hi...follow this http://techsahre.blogspot.in/2011/04/salesforce-native-datepicker-year.html.

Comment: good spot pankaj; if already within Visualforce context, a component on the page is way better

Comment: I have a page with multiple date fields, and I only want to do this on some of them (ie. birthdays can be in past, to do items can only be in the future).  Any tips on implementing something like that?

Comment: @user320 RE: "Don't trample the `window.onload`" mention, you could alternatively leverage the Salesforce provided function `sfdcPage.appendToOnloadQueue` to push your script into the array of functions SFDC naturally calls in the page lifecycle. `sfdcPage.appendToOnloadQueue(function() { /* Your script here */ });`

Answer (score 3):

Here's one [Workaround](http://codebycody.com/2011/05/13/fix-for-salesforce-com-date-picker-year-limitation/) i found out in one of the blog.

**Note**: This will not work if your the "sidebar" attribute in your page is set to "false".

Comment: The workaround link is dead

Answer (score 2):

Since you're in Visualforce, you may want to use a custom Datepicker - that way you have more control in how it looks and works.

Bob Buzzard has a blog post related to exactly this issue, of wanting to show different year values: [Integrate custom date picker with Visualforce](http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2012/03/custom-date-picker.html).

Personally, though, I'd go with the jQuery UI Datepicker - it has a configuration option that lets you [display year menus](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year), with 10 years displayed before and after the current year . To implement in Visualforce, simply render your Date field with an `<apex:inputText value="{!record.My_Date_Field__c}" id="myDateField"/>`, and then use jQuery to apply the Datepicker widget to the generated input field:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="CloseDateController">

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <apex:stylesheet value="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.0/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"/>

  <apex:form >
  <apex:pageBlock title="Set Close Date">
    <apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:outputLabel value="Close Date"/>
            <apex:inputText value="{!closeDate}" id="myDateField"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!saveDate}" value="Save" rerender="closeDateOutput"/>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
  </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>

  <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.CloseDate}" rendered="true" id="closeDateOutput"/>

    <script>
      jQuery(function(){
        var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
        $j("input[id$=myDateField]").datepicker({
           changeYear: true,
           changeMonth: true,
           dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy"
        });
      });

   </script>

</apex:page>

public class CloseDateController {

  private Opportunity opp;
  private String closeDate;

  public String getCloseDate() {
   return closeDate;
  }

   public void setCloseDate(String value) { 
     closeDate = value;
     // We expect a date in MM/DD/YYYY format,
     // with the Month, coming from JavaScript, being one less than it should 
     List<String> parts = value.split('/');
     opp.CloseDate = Date.newInstance(
       Integer.valueOf(parts[2]),
       Integer.valueOf(parts[0])+1,
       Integer.valueOf(parts[1])
     );
   }

   public CloseDateController(ApexPages.StandardController ctl) {
      Opportunity o = (Opportunity) ctl.getRecord();
      Date d = o.CloseDate;
      closeDate = d.month() + '/' + d.day() + '/' + d.year();
   }

   public PageReference saveDate() {
     upsert opp;
     return ApexPages.currentPage();
   }

 }
```

Comment: If this works, it's probably the most elegant solution I've seen for this scenario.

Comment: http://techsahre.blogspot.in/2011/04/salesforce-native-datepicker-year.html will surely works

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control startdate and end date values with more precision, you can use the javascript snippet given in below link,

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F000000090hiIAA

Basically it gets the element by ID and injects the html  values into the year dropdown. In the above link example is given with jQuery. But it can be done using plain javascript also.