# Date of Birth field - Calendar years not showing earlier years in console

Tags: customization, console

i have go through a few guide available [here](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/General-Development/Date-of-Birth-field-Calendar-years-don-t-go-back-before-this/td-p/120133/highlight/false) and this guide doenst help on console. can anyone help how can i make my date field Years drop down in console showing previous years?

Comment: Please find related post http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7944/standard-datepicker-year-values

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at this.Pretty neat.

http://www.greytrix.com/blogs/salesforce/changing-the-date-range-in-standard-salesforce-calendar/

Comment: I have tried that but it does not take effect in my service cloud console.

Comment: Are your sure because I implemented this in a vf page and checked it in the service console. Works for me. You can try checking if there are any jquery errors in the javascript console.

Comment: i am using standard console contact layout and have section which is VF page. i added the script in it but doesn't help.

Comment: I am using this @swatkat and i will try to check dynamic date every year , very thanks full for help us.

Answer (score 0):

Hi as salesforce doesn't show this feature till before launch of winter 14 ,as winter14 release as new feature where we can use html5 in VisualForce pages.

use this tag

here is tag

```
<apex:page  docType="html-5.0">
      <apex:inputField value="{! Contact.Birthdate }" type="date" 
                showDatePicker="false"
                /> 
</apex:page>
```

note in order to excetue html5 tags use docTyep="html-5.0"

for more reference follow this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp)

Answer (score 0):

here is my code we are try this .

```
<script src ="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(window).load(function (){
    var d = new Date();
    var vdate = document.getElementById("calYearPicker").innerHTML = d.getFullYear();
      $("#calYearPicker").html('')
      for(var i=1900; i<= vdate+1; i++){
        $("#calYearPicker").append("<option value= '"+ i +"'>"+i+"</option>")
      }
    });
    </script>
```